# How do I count the number of unique visitors to Pages

Tags: nodes

How do I get the number of Unique visitors to the page? I need to get Unique visitors on each page or at the content level, how can I get it?

Comment: Is it D7 or D8?

Answer (score 0):

You can not with only a Drupal instance, it's an architecture issue. But you can use [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) (former Piwik) for such needs.

If it is a simple scenario, you could get along with setting your own visit-cookie - but you need to program a module for this. And the result will be fuzzy cause of numerous caching steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take [Node View Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module as a base and add the IP condition to be used.

Another solution is to have Google Analytics installed and request the data through some API.